# Regex expression doesn't take the last result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a list of logs and I need to separate them one by one. I tried to come up with a regex expression:

```
/(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})[\s\S]+?(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})/gm
```

that separates correctly one log from another, but it doesn't take the last log... (I know that in this expression I am looking for a string that starts with a particular format of a timestamp and end before the next timestamp -> this is why the last log it's not being identified) but I don't know how to add that condition...  I tried it like this:

```
/(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})[\s\S]+?((?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})|\Z)/gm
```

And it works in PHP but not in Javascript.... (and I need to use it in a javascript app... T_T)

I've tried any other way I could think of, but no still no luck...

This is the set of logs that I'm tried to process:

```
2019-05-07 10:51:01,566 [6] INFO App1 - Process File Upload started!
2019-05-07 10:51:12,856 [6] ERROR App1 - Error at UploadDailyAt 
Error details:
   at Something...
2019-05-07 10:51:12,856 [6] INFO App1 - Wait Time for export file in Minutes: 5
```

Comment: Remove the multiline flag and use `$` instead of `\Z`

Comment: Works just fine for me https://regex101.com/r/ctb59t/1

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, it works now, thanks a million times! The only thing that's left is `\r\n` at the end of a line. Can I remove them by modifying the regex expression is some way?

Comment: If you want to remove trailing newline characters, you can use `trim()` (this will also remove other leading/trailing whitespace characters)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've tried to use `trim()` like this: `let regexArray = log.trim().match(regexString); console.log(regexArray);` but it doesn't remove them... PS. `log` is my full string